# Getting value of multiple text inputs by class name and only returning value from the one that has value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple text inputs that all share the same class name.

Assuming the code has been written so that only one of those text inputs can have value at any one time, is it possible to search for the value of those text inputs by class name and only return the value of the one that has data written in it by the user?

For the purpose of this question, how would I get that value to be returned in the alert box in the code below?

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input").value;

alert("input");
```

If it isn't possible using class names, is there an alternative solution that would achieve the same effect?

I would rather avoid having to give each text input an id and write code for each one, hence wanting to use class names.

Comment: For one, I think you need to remove the quotes around input in your alert. alert("input") will display an alert with the string "input"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//find all the elements, filter out the ones without a value, get the value
$('.theClass').filter(function(){ return this.value.trim(); }).val()
```

```js
var $inputs = $('.aClass');

$inputs.on('input', function(){
    $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.trim());
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
  console.log(
    $inputs.filter(function(){ return this.value.trim(); }).val()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type="text" class="aClass"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="aClass"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="aClass"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="aClass"></div>
<div><button>Get Value</button></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this below code,

```
    var matches = document.getElementsByClassName('input');

    for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++) {
        //do action
        console.log(matches[i].value)
    }
```